# How to export Parallels Win 7 VM into AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-7, virtualization, migration

Is there any elegant way to transfer a complete Win 7 server installation from a Parallels Desktop (Mac) VM into an AWS EC2 instance?

Comment: You can import VMs from VMWare vSphere, Citrix Xen, or Microsoft Hyper-V. No Parallels.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to convert it to a VMDK using existing tools. (I suggest the VMware converter http://www.vmware.com/download/eula/converter_starter.html) Just run it within the virtual OS and point it to another drive, then import the VMDK into AWS, and create an AMI based off it.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Desktop OS like Windows 7 is not supported by Amazon VM Import. See [full list](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#What_operating_systems_are_supported)

But there are clouds that do support running Desktop OSes.